# Аналог ip2long и long2ip в Java

Tags: php, java

Как в Java реализовать методы по преобразованию ip в long и обратно, как `ip2long` и `long2ip` функции в php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для преобразования `ip` в `long` по аналогии `ip2long`, создайте метод `ipToLong()` с принимаемым параметром типа `String`. Пример принимаемой строки: `"192.168.1.1"`.

```
private static long ipToLong(String ip) {
    String[] ipSplit = ip.split("\\.");
    long longIp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ipSplit.length; i++)
    {
        longIp += Integer.parseInt(ipSplit[i]) * Math.pow(256, 3 - i);
    }
    return longIp;
}
```

Для обратного преобразования `long` в `ip` по аналогии `long2ip`, создайте метод `longToIp()` с принимаемым параметром типа `long`. Пример принимаемого параметра: `3232235777`.

```
    private static String longToIp(long longIp)
    {
        return ((longIp >> 24) & 0xFF) + "." +

                ((longIp >> 16) & 0xFF) + "." +

                ((longIp >> 8) & 0xFF) + "." +

                (longIp & 0xFF);
    }
```

В первом методе строка с `ip` разбивается на массив из четырех чисел. Затем числа перемножаются на 256 возведенное в степень 3, 2, 1, 0 соответственно для каждого числа. Сумма чисел после проведенных операций `long` полученного `ip`.

Во втором методе для преобразования `long` обратно в `ip` используется побитовый сдвиг принимаемого `long`. Принимаемый `long` поочередно сдвигается на 24, 16, 8 бит соответственно, для последнего числа сдвиг не требуется, после чего биты преобразуются в соответствии логического оператора `&` с байтом `0xFF`.

[@tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun) посоветовал в методе `ipToLong()` также использовать побитовый сдвиг вместо метода `Math.pow()`, реализация которого показана ниже:

```
private static long ipToLong(String ip)
    {
        String[] ipSplit = ip.split("\\.");
        return ((Long.parseLong(ipSplit[0]) << 24)) +

                ((Long.parseLong(ipSplit[1]) << 16)) +

                ((Long.parseLong(ipSplit[2]) << 8)) +

                (Long.parseLong(ipSplit[3]));
    }
```

Comment: Использовать возведение в степень, там, где можно обойтись сдвигом, как-то странновато

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например так:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

// ... Где-то тут определяется нужный класс

public static long ipToLong(String stringIp) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(stringIp);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).wrap(address.getAddress());
    return (long)bb.getInt();
}

public static String longToIp(long longIp) throws UnknownHostException {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt((int)longIp);
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(bb.array());
    return address.getHostAddress();    
}
```

Преимущества такого способа в минимуме "велосипедов". На самом деле в целом идея преобразовывать "long" в "IP" и обратно, в настоящее время теряет актуальность, поскольку IPv6 не поместится даже в Java-long (который длинее, чем в PHP на 32-битных системах). Скорее всего в задачах, где нужны были "long", в Java лучше оперировать массивами байтов.